# How to create a new variable based on multiple conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, transform

I'm working with [frames](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/frames-dataset/#!stats) and I'm trying to transform a variable where months and dates are strings into a new variable `season`. However my if conditional statements below will only make a new var `season` where everything is `spring` (probably because it's the first if statement), everything else is ignored.

Anyone got any clue as to why?

```py
if 'september' or 'october' or 'november' in labels['str_date']:
    labels['season'] = 'spring'
if 'december' or 'january' or 'febuary' in labels['str_date']:
    labels['season'] = 'summer'
if 'march' or 'april' or 'may' in labels['str_date']:
    labels['season'] = 'autumn'
if 'june' or 'july' or 'august' in labels['str_date']:
    labels['season'] = 'winter'
else: 
    labels['season'] = 'null'
    
#labels.loc[(labels.season == 'spring')].value_counts()
#labels
sns.countplot(x='season', data=(labels))
plt.show()
```

[image]

subset of the df = `labels`:

Comment: you cannot do `if a or b in list`. Because 'or' and 'and' must be used between booleans like 'true or true'. So you have to write a full sentence `if a in list or b in list`

Answer (score 2):

That's not the way `or` or `in` work.  This statement is processed as

```py
if ('september') or ('october') or ('november' in labels['str_date']):
```

Non-empty strings are treated as `True` values, and anything OR-ed with `True` is `True`:

```py
if True or True or ('november' in labels['str_date']):
```

You can use the following:

```py
month = labels['str_date').split()[0]

if month in ('september', 'october', 'november'):
    labels['season'] = 'spring'
...
```